# Power apps query to SharePoint On-premise

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, powerapp

We have an o365 environment with federated users from AD. There is an ADFS in place.

Is there a way to call/query on premise SharePoint list data using the user context(permissions) to fetch data and use it in the power apps (possibly via REST)? There is the the Gateway built for this purpose, but we would like to query directly without using the gateway. Is this scenario achievable?

The OAuth token from PowerApps does not allow the user through in on prem. Is there something that can be does to allow this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, This scenario is unachievable till now.

PowerApps is only a **cloud-based** solutions that **can't** be used directly (`without using the gateway`) to retrieve data from SharePoint On-Premises Lists.

So in order to use PowerApps with SharePoint on-prem, you should create a **single gateway** to create connections to Sharepoint on-premises lists data sources.

Read more at

- [Support for on-premises SharePoint lists](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/support-for-sharepoint-on-premises/)
- [SHAREPOINT DESIGNER 2016 AND INFOPATH 2016 IN SHAREPOINT SERVER 2016, WHAT’RE THE ALTERNATIVES?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/)